# Why isn't BootStrap column offset working?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to build a website with flash-cards to help learn the Hebrew alphabet. My `Card` partial view looks like this:

```
@model FlashCards.MultipleChoice.ViewModels.CardViewModel

<div class="index-card">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-5"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            @Model.Numeric
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 text-center card-symbol">
            @Html.Raw(Model.UnicodeEscape)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
            @Model.Name
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the `col-md-offset` works on all but the first row, causing the card to render as in the below image:

[image]

Now why isn't the `1` in the image offset like the glyph and the name for the letter Aleph?

My CSS file for these cards only contains the following so far:

```
.index-card {
    height: 150px;
}

    .index-card .card-symbol {
        font-size: large
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're using the offset classes wrong; do not apply them to empty divs.

Your text is centered. Second and third rows have widths of 8 columns. It looks like the offset is working but it really isn't. The first row is only 2 columns wide. None of your offset divs are having any effect on the layout.

You need to do something like this, at the very least:

```html
<div class="index-card">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-2 text-center">
      @Model.Numeric
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center card-symbol">
      @Html.Raw(Model.UnicodeEscape)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center">
      @Model.Name
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not too used to this grid and I confused empty divs with a width and empty divs with an offset. I learned something here.

Comment: No worries, glad to help!